# Moving Highcharts series in front of other series with toFront() doesn't work

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a scatter plot with 7 series, each having  ~2100 points. I'm highlighting points by selecting them (since there's apparently no way to programatically add a pair of static crosshair lines on a point) but the problem is, sometimes they appear behind another series entirely so they're not really visible. To try to fix this I've done:

```js
point = chart.get(correctedString);
if (point !== null) {
 chart.series[point.series.index].group.toFront();
 point.graphic.toFront();
 point.select(true, true);
}
```

I'm trying to bring the group forward first, then the point, then enlarge it by selecting it. This doesn't work in any order. The point's `toFront()` call works just fine, as does the `select()`. Just the group that doesn't want to go to the front... not sure why.

Ideally, I'd like the single point to be sent to the front of ALL series and not have to bring the entire series to the front along for the ride, but as far as I know that's also impossible. Am I right about that?

Comment: You are right, it's not possible to bring to front only one point of the series. Simply points are in groups, so if group is behind another, then `toFront()` will work only within the group. And your code may not work, because you probably want to use `series.markerGroup` not `series.group` ;)

Comment: That did the trick, thanks. If you want to put that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, it's not possible to bring to front only one point of the series. Simply points are in groups, so if group is behind another, then `toFront()` will work only within the group.

Your code may not work, because you probably want to use `series.markerGroup` not `series.group`.